# How can I set the current value of a MultiSelector's SelectedItems property?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

For non-collection WPF DependencyProperties, if I need to update the property's value without affecting any of its bindings, I use:

```
SetCurrentValue(DependencyProperty, value);
```

Is there an equivalent function I can use for the MultiSelector's SelectedItem**s** dependency property? When I try to access it through the DataGrid, I can see that the SelectedItems DP is not public. Furthermore, there's a SelectedItemsImplProperty that is internal. How can I set a current value on this DP?

Thanks,

-Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unbelievable. I was looking for the same question on net about 15 min ago and you where thinking about it in 2 hours ago! Small world, huh? Try following code:

## code

```
if (!this.IsUpdatingSelectedItems) 
{
     this.BeginUpdateSelectedItems();
     foreach (object item in itemsToAdd)
     {
         this.SelectedItems.Add(item);
     }
     this.EndUpdateSelectedItems(); 
}
```

Comment: This approach does help, thanks. One thing to consider is that if you're not using a class derived from DataGrid, you won't have access to IsUpdatingSelectedItems and Begin/EndUpdateSelectedItems() since they're protected. So, if you need to access non-public members, you can use reflection to call the SelectItem method on the DataGrid, which essentially encapsulates the code you described above.

Comment: I think it needs a syncronized block! While seems that BeginUpdateSelectedItems() affects on IsUpdatingSelectedItems.